# How should I model circular dependencies in FRP (Rx.Net)?

Tags: c#, system.reactive, reactive-programming, circular-dependency, rx.net

I am trying to learn more about functional-reactive programming by using Rx.Net to implement Tic-Tac-Toe. The problem I am having is that there seems to be a circular dependency in my game-logic.

The `commands` stream (`PlaceToken`, `ResetGame`, etc.) is generated from user-input streams.

The current state of the game (`boardStates`) is derived by applying `commands` to the previous state, starting with the initial state:

```
var initialBoardState = new BoardState();

var boardStates = commands
    .Scan(initialBoardState, (boardState, command) => command.Apply(boardState))
    .DistinctUntilChanged();
```

However, the `commands` stream should depend on the `boardStates` stream. This is because the valid set of commands changes with the current state.

For example, the `PlaceToken` command should only be issued when the user clicks on an empty tile, but the set of empty tiles is defined by the current state!

So to summarise, I have two streams which seem to depend on each-other. How should I work around this in functional-reactive programming?

Comment: You really need a [mcve] for this.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

While @LeeCampbell's solution does work, it requires making your core model classes mutable. Instead, I found it best to copy the approach taken by cycle.js. You can see their explanation [here](https://egghead.io/lessons/rxjs-read-effects-from-the-dom-click-events).

The problem is that we have a cycle. The stream of actions depends on the stream of board states, which in turn depends on the stream of actions:

```
boardStream = f(actionStream)
actionStream = g(boardStream)
```

The cycle.js solution is to use a proxy stream to wire everything together:

```
// Create a proxy
proxyActionStream = new Stream()

// Create our mutually dependent streams using the proxy
boardStream = f(proxyActionStream)
actionStream = g(boardStream)

// Feed actionStream back into proxyActionStream
actionStream.Subscribe(x => proxyActionStream.OnNext(x))
```

In Rx.Net land, the proxy stream should be a `ReplaySubject`.

The only place you have to be careful is with run-away feedback loops: if your streams never stabilize then they hit an infinite loop! It is helpful to think of the streams as a mutual recursion.

Answer (score 1):

Not everything needs to be an event. Remember Rx/Callbacks are a way of allowing something that you depend on, to call you back (without taking a dependency on you).

As a rule of thumb

1. Circular dependencies indicate a design flaw
2. Send Commands, Receive Events

*2)* can also be translated to

> Just call methods on your dependencies to change their state, but subscribe to their events to see their changes

So instead of thinking of Commands as a stream, you should think of user actions as a stream that when listened to may create a command.

So the BoardState might look something like this

```
public class BoardState
{
    public void PlaceToken(PlaceTokenCommand placeToken)
    {
        //Process, then raise event
    }

    public void Reset()
    {
        //Process, then raise event
    }

    public IObservable<?> StateUpdates()
    {

    }
}
```

and the ViewModel(?) code might look something like this

```
public class TicTacToeViewModel
{
    private readonly BoardState _board;
    public TicTacToeViewModel()
    {
        _board = new BoardState();
        MoveTokenCommand = new DelegateCommand(MoveToken, CanMoveToken);
        ResetBoardCommand = new DelegateCommand(_board.Reset);

        board.StateUpdates(state => UpdatePresentation(state));
    }

    public DelegateCommand MoveTokenCommand { get; private set;}
    public DelegateCommand ResetBoardCommand { get; private set;}


    private void MoveToken()
    {
        var token = CurrentToken;
        var location = ActiveLocation;
        var cmd = new PlaceTokenCommand(token, location);
        _board.PlaceToken(cmd);
    }

    private bool CanMoveToken()
    {
        //?
    }
}
```

But as @Enigmativity, requests in the comments, without a MCVE it is very hard to offer sensible help.

Last note, While Rx is Functional and it is Reactive, the zealots would object to Rx being considered *FRP* (see Conal, Behaviours etc).